# Conversion .keras model to .tflite

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tflite

I'm trying to convert my .keras model to .tflite because I need to optimize my hand recognition model.
Here is my suspicious lines:

```
model = tf.keras.models.load_model('model/model_save/hand_tracking_model.keras')
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model)
tflite_model = converter.convert()
```

Version of packages I've got:
Python 3.9.13
Tensorflow 2.15.0
tf-nightly 2.17.0.dev20240306
tflite 2.10.0

Comment: What is the actual problem or question here? Suspicious lines says nothing.